# Phonegap can't get iOS push notification on device

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, notifications, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm building a Cordova hybrid application, which uses push notification plugin - https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push. For Android part I use gcm and for iOS I use APNs. Everything works with Android devices. I can send APN to server and it shows that everything is okay, but I can't get it on my iPhone device. I can get iPhone registration id and I send my notification directly to that device, but function, which is responsible for handling notification, doesn't react. I also tried to re-install the plugin, but that didn't help.

How I am receiving my notification in js:

```
    var push = PushNotification.init({
        "android": {
            "senderID": "xx"
        },
        "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"}, 
        "windows": {} 
    });

    push.on('registration', function(data) {
        //I can get registration id here
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });

    push.on('notification', function(data) {
        //this place doesn't work
        alert("notification event");
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });

    push.on('error', function(e) {
        alert("push error");
   });
```

This is how I send my notification to server in php:

```
$deviceToken = 'xxx';
$passphrase = 'xx';
$message = 'My first push notification!';
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );
$payload = json_encode($body);
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;
fclose($fp);
```

This outputs that 'Message successfully delivered'. Is there a chance that this doesn't work on iOS 9? (I have tested just on one device) Maybe there are some other ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: are you sending to APNs sandbox? Dev builds of apps only send via sandbox. Production/distribution builds use standard APNs

Comment: I am now on developing mode so I use sandbox